# How can I create a running average of 15 values from .txt file?

Tags: c++, arrays, average, file-io

I am trying to fine tune a program that takes a series of values from a .txt file, and creates a running average of 15 values. For example, it will read the first 15 values, output this average next to the 15th number, then it will read values 2-16, take the average and output it next to the 16th number. Then it will read values 3-17, take the average and output it next to the 17th number and so forth. Unfortunately I haven't made much progress in my program but here is the code I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

#define ARRAYSIZE  10000
#define OTHER 10000

int main(void)
{
    //things needed
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    double xArray[ARRAYSIZE];
    double yArray[ARRAYSIZE];
    double average;
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2=0;
    double average2;

    infile.open("data.txt");
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cout << "can't open data.txt\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < 15; z++) {
        infile >> xArray[ARRAYSIZE];
        sum = xArray[ARRAYSIZE] + sum;
        average = sum / (z+1);
    }

    outfile << xArray[ARRAYSIZE] << ", " << average << endl;
    sum2 = sum;

    //Running Average
    for (int x = 0; x < 10000 && !infile.eof(); x++) {
        infile >> yArray[OTHER]; 
        sum2 = yArray[OTHER] + sum2;
        average2 = sum2 / (x + 16);
        cout << yArray[OTHER] << ", " << average2 << endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can get the average of everything but I can't separate my average into 15 value segments.

Comment: Your indices `xArray[ARRAYSIZE]` and `yArray[OTHER]` are incorrect.  They access one element past the end of your arrays.  The way you've written your code, you don't need arrays at all, actually, so you might re-think what you're doing.  If you really do want a sliding-window average, you need to do something with the last 15 samples, but you're only looking at the most recent sample.

Comment: @JoeZ can you give me a code example of what you mean? How would you do it without arrays?

Comment: @HansPassant what exactly do you mean by switching the for loops?

Comment: I'm not saying you can do it without arrays.  I'm saying your code isn't using the arrays it declares, because it's always reading and writing the same element.  That suggests you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to just hand you working code.  But to get you un-stuck, consider the following approach:

1. Declare an array that holds exactly 15 elements.
2. Initialize a sum to 0.
3. Loop over all incoming elements, doing the following:

   1. Keep an index value `i` that starts at 0 for the first element and counts upward from there.
   2. If you've seen *more* than 15 elements, subtract the element at array position `i % 15` from the sum.  This removes elements from the rolling sum that slide out of your window.
   3. Read one new element in from the file.
   4. Add the new element to the sum.  This adds elements to the rolling sum as they slide into your window.
   5. Store the new element at array position `i % 15`.
   6. If you've seen 15 or more elements, output your moving average as `sum / 15.0`.

The idea of a moving average is to only average the elements in the window.  The array keeps track of the window.

With the algorithm above, the sum keeps track of the total sum of elements in the window.  As you add elements to the window, you add them to the sum.  As you remove elements from the window, you remove them from the sum.

The moving average, then, is just the sum divided by the size of the window.